# Proportion of dataset equal to a value

Tags: r

I have the following dataset called **asteroids**

```
3   4   3   3   1   4   1   3   2   3
1   1   4   2   3   3   2   6   1   1
3   3   2   2   2   2   1   3   2   1
6   1   3   2   2   1   2   2   4   2
```

I need to find out what proportion of this dataset is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that 'asteroids' is a `data.frame`, `unlist` it, get the `table` and find the proportion with `prop.table`.

```
prop.table(table(unlist(asteroids)==1))
#    FALSE  TRUE 
#    0.75  0.25
```

Or as @Richard Scriven mentioned, we can convert the `data.frame` to a logical `matrix`, and use `table` directly on it as 'matrix' is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.

```
prop.table(table(asteroids == 1))
```

Comment: `unlist()` is unnecessary. Just `prop.table(table(asteroids == 1))`

Comment: @RichardScriven  Thanks for your comments.  I added it.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a specific value in mind you can just do an equality comparison and then use `mean` on the resulting logical vector.

```
> asteroids <- scan(what=numeric())
1: 3 4 3 3 1 4 1 3 2 3 1 1 4 2 3 3 2 6 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 1 6 1 3 2 2 1 2 2 4 2
41: 
Read 40 items
> mean(asteroids == 1)
[1] 0.25
```

This works since the equality comparison will give TRUE and FALSE and when T/F are coerced numerically they become 1s and 0s so `mean` ends up giving us the proportion of TRUEs.

I assumed asteroids was a vector. You don't specify in your question but if it's a different type of structure you'll probably need to coerce it into a vector in some way or another.